# sifr not working in browsers, but can see it in dreamweaver preview

Tags: php, html, sifr

this is my first time trying to use sifr, so pleave be gentle and forget my noobness :).

ive been having some problems getting sifr to work... when finally it looked like it did (the dreamweaver preview saw the font change), no browser can see it...

http://www.creatica.ro/in2itivetest/index.html

this is the site im working on.

thank you in advance for helping.

Answer (score 0):

One of your javascript includes is returned as a 404, meaning you're referring to a non-existing file (js-file) from your HTML document.

http://www.creatica.ro/Scripts/swfobject_modified.js is the path of the missing file. Would make sense for that to screw up something to do with flash I reckon :)

Check where the file actually is and move it or change the URL to reflect the correct path.

PS: Nice site by the way. Even though I found the top menu slightly annoying.. (the hover effect feels over the top and sluggish)

Comment: actually i gave up on sifr just this morning as i couldnt get it working whatever i tried...  switched to typeface right now, and it seems to work and look right (also much easier to set up and use then sifr) and about that missing javascript, i got no idea where its from... deleted it and everything seems in order. rly nice to know some1 likes my site, and i will probably work on that menu to make it faster if nothing else. This is the 3rd site i ever made, so the encouragement really raises my moral :D